# replace page contents with another

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with a submit button. I want to display the results on the same page.

Doing something like this works.

```
<a href="result.php" target="_self"><input type="button" value="signup" /></a>
```

where `result.php` has the result page i want to display.

But i want to achieve this with a single file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="<?php htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="get" name="form">
                <label>Enter: <input type="text" name="input"/></label><br />
                <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter"/>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['enter']))
    {
        //i want this new page to replace the one already there.
    print('
    <html>
        <head>result</head>
        <body>
            <form action="index" method="get" name="form">
            <label>You entered : <input type="text" value="'.$_GET['input'].'"/></label>
        </body></html>
        ');
    }
    ?>
```

But it just appends the result to the existing page.

Any help how to replace?

Comment: [`if(isset[$_GET['signup']))` syntax error.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) --- [Proper syntax here...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) *as a sidenote*.

Comment: `signup.php?signup` is how you'll get your GET array, if that's what the question is about. remember your braces `if(isset($_GET['signup'])){...}`

Comment: The question is how to refresh a page without the form that was on it and showing a different form instead.

Comment: if not, then you'll need to change `<input type="button" value="signup" />` to `<input type="submit" value="signup" name="signup" />` one of those will do the same result. and add a header to the same page. Maybe I'm not grasping the question neither, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify the `$_GET['enter']` before print anything. like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if(!isset($_GET['enter']) { ?>

        <form action="" method="get" name="form">
            <label>Enter: <input type="text" name="input"/></label><br />
            <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Enter"/>
        </form>

        <?php } else { ?>
            <p> other html </p>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```